# Issue with $.when

Tags: javascript, jquery, client, jquery-deferred

I want to execute t2 function only after completion of t1 and t2

```
var t = function () {
   setTimeout(function () {
     console.log("t");
   }, 5500);
};

var t1 = function () {
   setTimeout(function () {
     console.log("t1");
   }, 500);
};

var t2 = function () {
   setTimeout(function () {
    console.log("t2");
   }, 100);
};

var r = function () { $.when(t(), t1()).then(t2); };
```

I am getting output:-
t2
t1
t
But I was expecting : 
t
t1
t2

Why *then* part is executing before t1 and t2.

Comment: $.when expects  promise arguments. Your functions return undefined.

Comment: `t1()` and `t2()` don't return promises, therefore `$.when()` has no idea when they finish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to return the promise from each async function to use the jQuery when and then:

```js
var t = function () {
   var d = new $.Deferred();
   setTimeout(function () {
     console.log("t");
     d.resolve()
   }, 500);
   return d.promise();
};

var t1 = function () {
   var d = new $.Deferred();
   setTimeout(function () {
     console.log("t1");
     d.resolve()
   }, 300);
   return d.promise();
};

var t2 = function () {
   var d = new $.Deferred();
   setTimeout(function () {
    console.log("t2");
    d.resolve()
   }, 100);
   return d.promise();
};

var r = function () { $.when(t()).then(t1).then(t2)};
r()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Note: last one is not required to return the promise from it though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `t` functions to work as expected. When we work with async operations, like setTimeout, we need to use a [deferred object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/).

```
var t = function () {
  var dfd = $.Deferred();

  setTimeout(function () {
    console.log("t");
    dfd.resolve('t');
  }, 5500);

  return dfd.promise();
};

var t1 = function () {
  var dfd = $.Deferred();

  setTimeout(function () {
    console.log("t1");
    dfd.resolve('t1');
  }, 500);

  return dfd.promise();
};

var t2 = function () {
  var dfd = $.Deferred();

  setTimeout(function () {
    console.log("t2");
    dfd.resolve('t2');
  }, 100);

  return dfd.promise();
};

var r = function () { $.when(t(), t1()).then(t2); };
```